# Two Mindstorms touch sensors: how to determine which sensor was pressed?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, ev3-g, sensor

[image]

I'm trying do make simple program. Two motors, two touch sensors. Sensor one increases speed, sensor two decreases.

The whole program works very well but only with one sensor. When I put some logic that has "Wait for sensor two" brick it just fools around.

The algorithm is very simple:

- Variable `i` - counts times sensors being pressed
- Variable `Znak` (eng. sign) causes variable `i` to decrease if negative or increase if positive.
- Motor speed is calculated by multiplying `i` by 10.

How can I solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 5):

I found an answer. I read in a book that I can't fork in a loop. But I can do up to 4 separate threads. So I did 3 threads:

1. Running/changing motors speed based on a variable "i" which is changed in other threads.
2. Waiting for a touch sensor A being bumped and increasing var "i".
3. Waiting for a touch sensor B being bumped and decreasing var "i".

[image: 3 threads]